# Unsigned int to signed floating point with python

Tags: python

Ok this has been bugging me for awhile now!

I have a Tri-Metric battery monitor which serial outputs data to an Arduino, where I convert and scale the output to be sent over *Modbus TCP* to my Raspberry Pi where it is then descaled and added to a mysql table. I,m currently using php to do this but want to move it to *python*, feeling that it would be more efficient than *PHP*.

The data say the amphours used by the system which goes negative when the battery is discharging after the sun goes down.

I scale the data by multiplying by 10 and converting to an unsigned 16 bit integer to meet Modbus specifications.

I need to know how i can change this unsigned 16 bit integer back to a signed floating point number to add to my database.

for example this is the raw data from *Modbus* 65365 the unscaled equivalent should be `-17.2 AmpHrs`.

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated.

This is how i convert it On the *Arduino*

```
cmdData[k] = '\0';        // add termination NULL char for float conversion:                                                       
cmdFloat = atof(cmdData); // convert char array upto NULL to float:                                                                     
cmdValue = int(cmdFloat * 10);  // convert to int16_t and scale up by 10:                                                                     

amp_hours = (uint16_t)cmdValue;
            Serial.print("Amp Hours: ");
}
Serial.println(cmdFloat);  //serial print the float value
}
```

In python i have tried

amphours = usamphours/10
if (amphours & 0x80000000):
amphours = -0x100000000 + amps

Also tried

amphours = amphours&0xffffffff

non of which works

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 3):

Converting from an unsigned integer to a signed integer of a specific size is easy in Python, if a bit tricky:

```
signed_value = unsigned_value if unsigned_value < (1 << bitsize-1) else unsigned_value - (1 << bitsize)
```

Once you have that, just divide by 10:

```
float_value = signed_value / 10.0
```

Comment: I tried this but got NameError: name 'bitsize' is not defined

Comment: @JohnWood this was just my attempt to make it generic. In the context of your question `bitsize` is 16.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with signed/unsigned integer, or converting between 16-bit/32-bit/64-bit integers in Python is a nightmare.

You can use [bitstring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3) module to convert between these types. For example:

```
a = bitstring.BitArray(uint=65365, length=32)
print a.float

9.159587412059167e-41
```

Answer (score 0):

This will depend entirely on how you are "converting to an unsigned 16 bit integer".

If this is being done as, for example, a raw cast from float to int (perhaps via a union), then you can decode this buffer within python using the `struct` module.  Pay attention to endianness.